# Jquery is the checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, checkbox

I have this line in a view of an MVC site which is within a ForEach loop that iterates over a set of times in a Model passed to the view.

```
<li data-cft-times="true" class="selectedList">@times.time
  <input type="checkbox" class="ficoEntry" checked="checked" data-cft-time="true" />
</li>
```

Then in my Jquery I am trying to see if the user has changed the checkboxes to deselect a time and I currently have this but it returns all the times not just the ones that still have the checkbox as ticked.

```
if ($('input[data-cft-time]').attr("checked") == "checked") {
            //do stuff...
}
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong as I have tried lots and seem to be getting nowhere but I know it's a simple issue that has me stuck...

Thanks.

EDIT...

I have tried both the posts below and neither work it looks like when I uncheck the checkbox the DOM is not updating as the HTML code using F12 still shows the following

```
<input type="checkbox" class="ficoEntry" checked="checked" data-cft-time="true" />
```

Am I missing something here....

MORE INFO..

```
<ul>
   <li class="selectedList" data-cft-times="true">2300
    <input class="ficoEntry" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cft-time="true">
   </li>
   <li class="selectedList" data-cft-times="true">0000
    <input class="ficoEntry" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cft-time="true">
   </li>
   <li class="selectedList" data-cft-times="true">0100
    <input class="ficoEntry" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cft-time="true">
   </li>
   <li class="selectedList" data-cft-times="true">0200
    <input class="ficoEntry" type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-cft-time="true">
   </li>
 </ul>
```

And here is the current JQuery.

```
$("li[data-cft-times]").each(function (index) {
        text = $(this).text().slice(0, 4);

        if ($('input[data-cft-time]').is(':checked')) {
            time += "{\"time\":\"" + text + "\"},";
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) then check the length of the collection, which will return 1 if your checkbox is checked:

```
if ($('input[data-cft-time]:checked').length)
        //do stuff...
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at my edits to my post showing my Code in more detail I have tried both methods posted here and neither work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if($('input[data-cft-time]').is(':checked')){

}
```

Comment: @CliffordAgius
I'm sure it does because i use it.
Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/vX3qV/

Comment: Have you looked at my edits to my post showing my Code in more detail I have tried both methods posted here and neither work.